# Editing the Entitlements.plist file using config.xml in Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, plist, phonegap-build, entitlements, phonegap

I am trying to use the Apple Pay cordova plugin using Phonegap build. Here is my entry in the config file:

```
     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-applepay-stripe" source="npm">
<param name="STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY" value="xxxxxxxx" />
<param name="STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
<param name="APPLE_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER" value="merchant.etc.etc" />
</plugin>
```

The plugin installs correctly however it will not work as I have not enabled the Apply Pay entitlement in Xcode as I am using a PC.

I am aware you can directly edit plist files from the phonegap build config.xml file like I have done here:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
<string>We are using the Photo Library for PayPal</string>...
```

So my question is how on earth do I edit the Entitlements.plist file so that I can enable ApplePay and add my merchant id?!

I have tried the following:

```
  <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Entitlements.plist" parent="com.apple.developer.in-app-payments">  
        <array>
            <string>merchant.etc.etc/string>
        </array>
</config-file>
```

but that hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which CLI version are you using? not all version have the Entitlements.plist files. Also, add the  `overwrite="true"` part

Comment: Also trying to figure this out -- wondering if you have made any progress

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like `config-file` only works in plugins for some reason. It seems like it should work in your project `config.xml`, but unfortunately it doesn't. However, you can use a local plugin to manage your entitlements to achieve more or less the same effect.

For example, `src/local-plugins/app-entitlements`

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="app-entitlements" spec="src/local-plugins/app-entitlements" />
```

You only need the `src/local-plugins/app-entitlements/plugin.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin id="app-entitlements" version="0.0.0" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0">
  <name>AppEntitlements</name>
  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*-Debug.plist" parent="com.apple.developer.in-app-payments">
      <array>
        <string>YOUR DEBUG MERCHANT ID HERE</string>
      </array>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="*-Release.plist" parent="com.apple.developer.in-app-payments">
      <array>
        <string>YOUR RELEASE MERCHANT ID HERE</string>
      </array>
    </config-file>
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

You can set other entitlements like push notifications or whatever you want here of course.

Now when you do a fresh `cordova platform add ios` it should create `Entitlements-*.plist` with these keys and you should be good to go.

**Keep in mind**, the "Capabilities" tab in Xcode is handled separately and is just a GUI helper. It won't reflect the entitlements for these files.